# Why waitpid is blocked with this particular case?

Tags: c

I want to understand how pipe works but i don't catch why waitpid is blocked in the case you execute my program with "ls -l /usr/bin" "grep ls".... If you take out the option -l it's works !
my_str_tab just put each word of the string into a charstar array.

```
void command_levels(int *pipe_fd, char **av, int idx, int pipe_save, int pipe_one)
{
    if (idx == 1)
        dup2(pipe_fd[1], 1);
    else if (idx > 1 && av[idx + 1] != NULL) {
        dup2(pipe_save, 0);
        dup2(pipe_fd[1], 1);
    }
    if (idx > 1 && av[idx + 1] == NULL) {
        dup2(pipe_save, 0);
        dup2(pipe_one, 1);
    }
}

void multiple_pipe_handle(char **av, char **env, int idx, int pipe_one)
{
    int pipe_fd[2] = {0, 0};
    char **command = NULL;
    static int pipe_save = 0;

    if (av[idx] == NULL)
        return;
    command = my_str_tab(av[idx], " ");
    pipe(pipe_fd);
    command_levels(pipe_fd, av, idx, pipe_save, pipe_one);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(pipe_fd[0]);
        close(pipe_fd[1]);
        execve(command[0], command, env);
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
        close(pipe_fd[1]);
        pipe_save = pipe_fd[0];
        multiple_pipe_handle(av, env, idx + 1, pipe_one);
        close(pipe_fd[0]);
    }
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
    int pipe_one = dup(1);

    multiple_pipe_handle(av, env, 1, pipe_one);
}
```

I expect the output of all word contains 'ls' but i'm in infinite loop..

Comment: Where do you read from the pipe?  The pipe has a buffer, but it will eventually block the writing process if no one reads the data from the other side.  The size of the buffer depends on the OS.  Most *nix style systems were 512 bytes, IIRC, but I believe Linux now has 64KB.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake when implementing pipelines.

When you pass `-l` to `ls`, it produces more output than when you don't pass that option.  That makes it completely fill up the pipe's internal buffer.  The kernel "blocks" it from continuing to execute until something reads from the other end of the pipe.  But nothing is reading from the other end of the pipe yet, because your parent program is waiting for `ls` to finish execution before it starts the `grep` process.  But `ls` will not finish execution until it can write more data to the pipe, so the overall program is deadlocked.

To fix this bug you must start *all* of the processes in the pipeline before you wait for *any* of them.  You can't do that with a single recursive call to `multiple_pipe_handle`.  You need two loops, one calling `fork` and one calling `waitpid`, and an array of subprocess PIDs.  If you intend to read from the final pipeline process's output in your parent process, you must read all of the data produced (until `read` signals EOF by returning zero bytes of data) *before* you start calling `waitpid`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response ! Can you give me a example please i don't understand a lot how to fix it..

Comment: If i understand if i want handle that case i can't do that in recursive mode ?

Comment: If i read the pipeline in the parent during the child write on it, where i supposed to stock this buffer and where i need to redirect it if i want handle multiple pipe ?